# Inserting a condition into query with indirect function. Receving #REF error

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements

I am querying information from a sheet named after the current month and year. The first formula works appropriately, but I need to add a condition where it only queries the rows where A is true on the dated sheet. The second formula is an idea of what I need, but I receive a #REF error. I would really appreciate any assistance with this as I have been stuck.

=QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&text(today(),"mmm yyyy")&"'!B4:Y"))

=QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&text(today(),"mmm yyyy")&"'!B4:Y where A=TRUE"))

[Sheet that I need to query data from, but only when check box in col A is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2x02.png)

I have tried multiple variations of this formula but have no found a format that works as desired. Always receive errors. The formula works as desired, but have not determined how to add the condition.

=QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&text(today(),"mmm yyyy")&"'!B4:Y where A=TRUE"))

Answer (score 0):

*Can you try:*

```js
=choosecols(QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&text(today(),"mmm yyyy")&"'!A4:Y"),"where A=TRUE"),sequence(columns(B:Y),1,2))
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! I think I was so stuck in trying to use the query function that I didn't consider the other formula options. I really appreciate your help.